# How to create such type of Jtable in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am newbie in jtable. i want to create a jtable in following  format as attached.

Please help me.

thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Sun Jtable tutorial would be a nice place to start studying.

Answer (score 1):

You need TreeTable component. Out of box swing does not provide such a component. But there are a number of libraries having it. For example, swingx(https://swingx.java.net/) - JXTreeTable component.
As an alternative you may implement your own component. Just search the Internet 'swing treetable component'

Answer (score 0):

As your image suggests, the component is generally referred to as a Property Editor. It's quite useful but Java Swing doesn't provide anything out of the box.

It's actually quite hard to do reliably, especially to support the various data types and not to mention the grouping aspect.

The speediest way of getting access to this type of component is to license it, as part of the [JIDE Grids](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm) package from JIDESoft. It's well built, well supported and will Just Work.

The best alternative (that I'm aware of) is from [L2FProd](http://www.l2fprod.com/common/). It's rather out of date and documentation isn't as good so you'll have to do a bit of reading of the source and a bit of googling. I've used it in the past though and did get reasonable results (although I didn't push it too hard).

If you are interested in literally how to create one of those components then the L2FProd source will be interesting to you, as would Netbeans, which also has a PropertyEditor component.